# Oracle Developer Tools for visual studio .net errors

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015

i had installed oracle 12c on pc and visual studio 2015 when i tried to install ODAC for integrating oracle over visual studio
then i got an error that
   [INS-50013] Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio .NET Error.
   Please install Visual Studio before you proceed with this installation
i forgot to mention that i had installed visual studio in one user and oracle in another user though i could access all the features of both oracle and visual studio
Please  give me the way to get out of this problem

Answer (score 3):

Now supported VS2015. still not support vs2017.
Anyone can get from this:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Updated: Now we can get ODAC for vs2017 at [ODAC for vs 2017](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2017-3806459.html)

Comment: Just a hint: Oracle DEV Tools are now avaliable for VS2017

Comment: Still I am facing same issue.

Comment: Same here, "ODAC for Visual Studio 2017 Downloads" installed but problem still present