# odac setup error ins-50013 Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio .NET Error

Tags: oracle, windows-10, odac

I move from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240247/odac-installation-perform-prerequisites-check-does-not-work) Beyond it is the same issue. The problem i am facing is different.

I want to install ODAC 122011. I have windows 64 bits.. And i am using Visual Studio 2017/2019 32bits.

I intented to install ODAC 64 bits, but, due to my Visual Studio version is 32 bits, i am trying to install ODAC 122011 called `ODTwithODAC122011.zip`. It is the ODAC 122011 32 bits i found.

When i run the setup, I face this problem..

[image]

Following this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946633/oracle-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-net-errors) I installed `ODTforVS2017_122011.exe` I think it was unnecesary.

Nevertheless, the problem remains.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install  Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio before installing  the ODAC

For EX: I installed - > ODTforVS2017_122010 for VS2017 from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacmsi-vs2017-downloads.html

then I installed ODAC it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

During the component selection of the install, Uncheck “Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio” option.
[image: ODAC 12c Release (12.2.0.1) Installer]